# Styling text content

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm making a stylesheet for a subreddit and I'm having an issue styling text.

The markup in this problem is as follows:

```
<span class="value">
    <span class="number">1</span>em;
</span>
```

I want to style that `em;` though I can't use `span.number + *` for some reason. Is there anyway I can select it without using `.value`?

Comment: You can't use the + selector because the em isn't in another element. It is simply text, which cannot be selected in it of itself in CSS. You would need to either encapsulate it in its own element or style it using a parent element.

Comment: So there's nothing I can do. That's all I needed to know.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a child of the number class.  It's a sibling since it's sitting outside of the inner span.

.value is the closest you can get to that particular text.

Comment: I know it's a sibling. That's why I used `+` and not `>`.

Comment: + can only be used on elements.  plain text is not an element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.
use pseudo class `:after` or use another element contain the **em**.

```css
.number:after{
  content: 'em';
  color: #c33;
  }
```

```html
<span class="value">
    <span class="number">1</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

You may have to use another span class surrounding the `em;` if you are unable to modify it using `.value`

Comment: Three answers and three down-votes hmm...

Comment: Because they all say I have to encase the text in another element or removing one. I can't do this being Reddit.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Reddit so unless you are able to tweak .value and not mess up the rest of your layout you may be stuck. No how bout that up-vote ;)

Comment: In Reddit all you can do is post very strict markdown and css. Just for future reference.